# Deleting nodes from VERY LARGE XML file in Powershell

Tags: c#, windows, powershell, .net-core

I am currently working on reading in a huge (3GB) XML file. This XML file is comprised of records, and i am looking to remove some depending on the attribute value (about 5% of the records) and then writing the remaining 95% to a new file.

My current code:

```
$Stopwatch = [System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch]::StartNew()
$xml = [xml]''
$xml.Load("C:\Users\Jack\Documents\development\record removal\records.xml")

$nodes = $xml.SelectNodes("//record[@category='APPLE'] | //record[@category='BANANA'] | 
//record[@category='ORANGE']")

foreach ($node in $nodes){
    $node.ParentNode.RemoveChild($node)
}

$xml.save("C:\Users\Jack\Documents\development\record removal\records-NEW.xml")
$StopWatch.Stop()
$StopWatch.Elapsed.TotalSeconds
```

The time taken to complete the task is too much, I need it to be more efficient. When I was doing it with just one category at a time it was a LOT faster, am I missing something obvious?

Should I be using something else like XMLReader?

XML Example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<records xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<record category="APPLE" sub-category="FRUIT">
</record>
<record category="BANANA" sub-category="FRUIT">
</record>
<record category="ORANGE" sub-category="FRUIT">
</record>
<record category="KIWI" sub-category="FRUIT">
</record>
<record category="GRAPE" sub-category="FRUIT">
</record>
</records>
```

**UPDATED SOLUTION**

Using the code by jdweng, I have imported it into my powershell code. Here is the full code:

```
$Stopwatch = [System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch]::StartNew()

$id = get-random

$Assem = (
"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\System.XML.dll",
"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\System.Xml.Linq.dll"
)

$Source = @”
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;


namespace Jack.Tools 
{
    public class Class$id
    {
        const string INPUT_FILENAME = @"C:\temp\old.xml";
        const string OUTPUT_FILENAME = @"C:\temp\new.xml";
        
        public static void method()
        {
            XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(INPUT_FILENAME);
            XmlWriterSettings settings = new XmlWriterSettings();
            settings.Indent = true;
            XmlWriter writer = XmlWriter.Create(OUTPUT_FILENAME, settings);
            writer.WriteStartDocument();
            writer.WriteStartElement("records");
            writer.WriteAttributeString("xmlns", "xsi", null, "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance");

            while (!reader.EOF)
            {
                if(reader.Name != "record")
                {
                    reader.ReadToFollowing("record");
                }
                if (!reader.EOF)
                {
                    XElement record = (XElement)XElement.ReadFrom(reader);
                    if ((string)record.Attribute("category") != "APPLE")
                    {
                        record.WriteTo(writer);
                    }
                }
            }
            writer.WriteEndElement();
            writer.WriteEndDocument();
            writer.Flush();
            writer.Close();
        }
    }
}
“@

Add-Type -AssemblyName Microsoft.CSharp
Add-Type -AssemblyName System
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Core
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Data
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Data.DataSetExtensions
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Xml
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Linq
Add-Type -ReferencedAssemblies $Assem -TypeDefinition $Source -Language CSharp 

iex "[Jack.Tools.Class$id]::method()"

$StopWatch.Stop()
$StopWatch.Elapsed.TotalSeconds
```

Comment: In that case, yes. The XmlReader should read records one at a time and write them to an XmlWriter, or discard them if they match the criteria. Right now you're loading 3GB of text in memory, parsing it into a lot more than 3GB of objects, scanning those 3GBs for records and finally writing the remaining 3GB- of nodes to disk. With an XmlReader/XmlWriter combination you'd only keep a single record at a time in memory plus the file buffers for the reader, writer streams

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos can this be done in Powershell? I am still learning Powershell and I also dont know how to code in C# yet.

Comment: You're already writing C# - the code you wrote creates and uses .NET classes directly. You lose any Intellisense and compilation benefits, which means writing this code is quite a bit trickier

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos thanks mate, I managed to import the c# method using Add-Type. I'll post the answer here with my code, thanks to you and jdweng it works perfectly!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try following :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication11
{
    class Program
    {
        const string INPUT_FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        const string OUTPUT_FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test1.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(INPUT_FILENAME);
            XmlWriterSettings settings = new XmlWriterSettings();
            settings.Indent = true;
            XmlWriter writer = XmlWriter.Create(OUTPUT_FILENAME, settings);
            writer.WriteStartDocument();
            writer.WriteStartElement("records");
            writer.WriteAttributeString("xmlns", "xsi", null, "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance");

            while (!reader.EOF)
            {
                if(reader.Name != "record")
                {
                    reader.ReadToFollowing("record");
                }
                if (!reader.EOF)
                {
                    XElement record = (XElement)XElement.ReadFrom(reader);
                    if ((string)record.Attribute("category") != "BANANA")
                    {
                        record.WriteTo(writer);
                    }
                }
            }
            writer.WriteEndElement();
            writer.WriteEndDocument();
            writer.Flush();
            writer.Close();
 


        }
    }

}
```